# Adding element to an array of arrays

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to call Model::insert() on this array to insert multiple data at once

```
"person" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Person 1"
      "place" => "Place 1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Person 2"
      "place" => "Place 2"
    ]
  ]
```

but the Model excepts a foreign key constraint department_id before it can be inserted into the DB. How do I add department_id to each array inside person array. Is there any other way apart from using for loops to iterate and placing it manually?

Result Array Should look like

```
"person" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "department_id" => 1
      "name" => "Person 1"
      "place" => "Place 1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "department_id" => 1
      "name" => "Person 2"
      "place" => "Place 2"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to Insert. You probably need to do something like `$department->people()->insert(...)`, which will automatically assign the correct `department_id`

Comment: There is no better way than loops. There are wrappers that could come in handy, but they loop internally too.

Comment: @TimLewis That would work but since OP wants a mass insert, wouldn't it increase DB roundtrips this way?

Comment: `$department_id = Department::create($data)->id;`
And I wanted to include this $department_id while using
`Person::insert($personArray);`

Comment: @nice_dev I don't know the inner workings of relationships well enough to comment on that concern, but I don't think so. You can test with any DB insert though; just try with `Model::insert(...)` vs `$relationship->models()->insert(...)` (replacing `...` with an array of multiple record to save), and checking how many queries are run via `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `count(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: @TimLewis Makes sense, will be interesting to figure that out. I will try it soon.

Comment: @AkshayRajeev I think without a loop it's not possible because of its bulk insertion which will make bulk insertion MySQL query too. So if we go to extends eloquent method that will also not going to help us. So you have to make `foreach` on `personArray` and add `department_id` via the `array_push()` and after that, you can insert the final array to the `person` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was similar to the comment by Tim Lewis

```
$department->people()->insert(...)
```

but insert didn't seem to assign id automatically

```
$department->people()->createMany(...)
```

worked
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update `Person` model and "department_id" to the `$fillable` array:

```
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'department_id',
];
```

Would be something similar to this:

```
<?php

// app/Models/Person.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'place',
        'department_id', // add department_id
    ];

   ...

}
```

Comment: Even if I add department_id as fillable, if I don't add it to my array before Eloquent create call, wouldn't it throw department_id has no default value?

Comment: It will throw error regardless added to fillable array or not, if it doesn't has a default value and its value isn't specified in insertion process

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no escaping loop here. You can use array_map here, but it also runs the loop internally.

```
Person::insert(array_map(function ($person) {
    $person['department_id'] = 1;
    return $person;
}, $persons));
```